# MSK - Is it possible to send records of different avro schemas in single topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, aws-msk

While using avro, is it possible to send records which have different schemas, in the same MSK topic? The schema registry to be considered here is Glue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to define your own subject naming strategy.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry#providing-schema-name

```
properties.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAMING_GENERATION_CLASS,
                "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.serializers.avro.CustomerProvidedSchemaNamingStrategy");
```

Comment: how do I use it in a python code, which uses kafka-python  along with aws-glue-schema-registry

Comment: The above library is only for Java. kafka-python doesn't have any libraries for serialization, so you'd need to implement your own HTTP request. Or ask your question here https://github.com/DisasterAWARE/aws-glue-schema-registry-python/issues